# I cannot access to reports through API

Tags: salesforce

I am not able to see any report through Salesforce API.

My Connected App is created.

The result of this call:

/services/data/v29.0/analytics

is:

{"report":"/services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports"}

but the result of:

/services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports

is :

[]

I am able to see SOME reports using the administrator credentials only, but not able to do the same with another users.

I have even cloned the administrator profile and assigned to a user to do my tests, but does not worked.

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: This should be on Sales force, I think you will get better results by not posting multiple threads.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33989/i-cannot-access-to-reports-through-api

Comment: Thank you! Any suggestion related to the question?